# Protect content of Map from modifications

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have a variable of type Map

```
Map<AiTile, List<AiTile>> result = new HashMap<AiTile, List<AiTile>>();
```

For example; I push a couple of AiTile-List inside of the map and then I erase content of the List with methode 'clear'. I want to protect content of the map when I erase content of the list, how can I do it ?

Comment: It would be better if you explain your functional requirement or add more examples about what you really need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Map.put(key, value)` adds a reference to the list, not the actual list contents. If I understood you correctly, you want to keep an old list values in the map and delete contents of the original list.

You might want to add a copy of the original list to the map, instead of the reference. E.g.:

```
map.put(key, new ArrayList<AiTile>(originalList));
```

#### UPDATE

If you would like to add key, value pairs to the map only if they're not already present and update already existing lists in the map, use `map.contains(key)` and `list.addAll(anotherList)`:

```
// if no key is present
if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
    // add key value pair
    map.put(key, value);
} else {
    // get the current list out of the map
    // and merge it with the new one
    map.get(key).addAll(value);
}
```

`NOTE:` By definition, `Lists` can contain duplicates. If you want to merge all items between two lists so that they don't contain duplicates, you might want to look at `Sets`.

[>> java doc is your best friend](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: I don't think `clone` is the right method to use - in any case you would need to cast. The copy-constructor of `ArrayList` is more appropriate.

Comment: @BoristheSpider good point. I've updated my answer to reflect your suggestion

Comment: I want to extend my question:

When I want to put a new couple of K,V inside of the map, if the K is already exist in map; it replace with the new V that is connected to K. I want to protect old K with old V and add new K and new V too, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to protect content of the map when I erase content of the
>   list, how can I do it

Then, you need to add a separate content list to the `HashMap` for each of the list:

```
   map.put(key, new ArrayList<AiTile>(list));
```

And if you need the map unmodifiable:

```
Map<AiTile, List<AiTile>>map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(result);
```

`Collections.unmodifiableMap(map)`: Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified collection. This method allows modules to provide users with `"read-only"` access to internal collections. Query operations on the returned collection `"read through"` to the specified collection, and attempts to modify the returned collection, whether direct or via its iterator, result in an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: While this is true, you should also add that you cannot add more values into `map`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, shamelessly pasted the documentation which says exactly that: it is read only :) Thank you

Comment: This doesn't prevent anyone from modifying the lists contained by the map.

Comment: Seriously, you should enhance your answers by adding at least some personal comments about how to design the solution using `Collections.unmodifiableMap` as part of the solution. What if OP only wants to add entries (key/value) to the map but never remove them unless the application stops or is undeployed?

Comment: I think so. I will make changes. @pamphlet actually did point my mistakes

Comment: @pamphlet is correct. This isn't the answer. The OP needs to copy the `List` on insertion into the `Map`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, Then i think the OP will need to keep a separate list to the map for each list with copying `new ArrayList<AiTile>(list)`. The problem i had with OP's title. Probably OP could clarify with an example

Comment: I only want to add lists to the map and then I don't want to change or erase the list that is inside of the map.